# NestedScrollView not work with CollapsingToolbar under CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a problem with scrolling behavior of `NestedScrollView` stop working when use `CollapsingToolbar`, Please help it seem content scroll only base on **`appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`** but cannot scroll content with `NestedScrollView`. some weird behavior is when click some `EditText`, in fragment layout and after dismiss virtual keyboard, scrolling work as it should be !!

## Library Version

```
// Sdk and tools
minSdkVersion = 16
targetSdkVersion = 26
compileSdkVersion = 26
buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'

// App dependencies
supportLibraryVersion = '27.1.0'
constraintLayout = '1.1.0-beta5'

implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$constraintLayout"
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

## UserProfileEditActivity

```
class UserProfileEditActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var appRepo: AppRepository

    companion object {
        fun createIntent(context: Context): Intent = Intent(context, UserProfileEditActivity::class.java)
                .apply { flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile_edit)

        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.contentContainer)
                ?: supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.contentContainer, UserProfileEditFragment())
                        .commit()

    }
}
```

## Layout: activity_user_profile_edit

just a repeat widget, to test scrolling content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgPeopleCover"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_cover_test"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvToolbarTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="ลิลลี่ ฮิกซ์"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

## Layout: fragment_user_profile_edit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextView.Secondary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ชื่อ" />

            <EditText
                style="@style/TextView.Big"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:hint="กรอกชื่อหมุด" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextView.Secondary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ชื่อ" />

            <EditText
                style="@style/TextView.Big"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:hint="กรอกชื่อหมุด" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextView.Secondary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ชื่อ" />

            <EditText
                style="@style/TextView.Big"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:hint="กรอกชื่อหมุด" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextView.Secondary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ชื่อ" />

            <EditText
                style="@style/TextView.Big"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:hint="กรอกชื่อหมุด" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextView.Secondary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ชื่อ" />

            <EditText
                style="@style/TextView.Big"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:hint="กรอกชื่อหมุด" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pinNameContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextView.Secondary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ชื่อ" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtPinName"
                style="@style/TextView.Big"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:hint="กรอกชื่อหมุด" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pinDescContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pinNameContainer">

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextView.Secondary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="นามสกุล" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtPinDesc"
                style="@style/TextView.Big"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:hint="กรอกรายละเอียด" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/genderContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pinDescContainer">

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextView.Secondary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="เพศ" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtGender"
                style="@style/TextView.Big"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_chevron_right"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_chevron_right"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:hint="ไม่ระบุ" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/endDateContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/genderContainer">

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextView.Secondary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="วันสิ้นสุด" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvEndDate"
                style="@style/TextView.Big"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_chevron_right"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_chevron_right"
                android:text="ไม่ระบุ" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/privacyContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/from_edge_space"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/endDateContainer">

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextView.Secondary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ผู้เห็นหมุด " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPrivacy"
                style="@style/TextView.Big"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_chevron_right"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_chevron_right"
                android:text="สาธารณะ(คนทั่วไปเห็น)" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this add **`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`** to your `NestedScrollView`

Use this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

Instead of this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

**EDIT**  remove **`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`** from your `FrameLayout`

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**EDIT 2**

> Use **`ViewPager`**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/htab_maincontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2fff00"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/htab_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/MyAppbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#F21757"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#F21757"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> Fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="NIELSH"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: @JongzPuangput remove ` app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`  from `Framelayout` than try becuse its working in my device

Comment: @JongzPuangput happy to help you

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: sorry my bad it's still not working, if we remove  app:layout_behavior from FrameLayout this layout will not below the appbar

Comment: for test case try to add it below app layout

Comment: @JongzPuangput check my **`EDIT2`**